# PIVOT query result issue

Tags: oracle, pivot

The following query

```
    SELECT pdate,empno, eNAME,
            workhrs,mealpanelty 
    from PRODUCTIVITY p,PRODUCTIVITYd d, emp e 
    where p.PRODUCTIVITYID=d.PRODUCTIVITYID and e.empno=p.employeeid
```

works fine results as

```
PDATE   EMPNO   ENAME   WORKHRS MEALPANELTY
03/08/2016  7698    BLAKE   50      4
03/08/2016  7698    BLAKE   7.58    -
03/08/2016  7698    BLAKE   8.12    -
03/08/2016  7698    BLAKE   7.34    -
03/08/2016  7698    BLAKE   8.02    -
```

While **PIVOT** query

```
WITH pivot_data AS (
            SELECT pdate,empno, eNAME,
                   workhrs,mealpanelty  
            from PRODUCTIVITY p,PRODUCTIVITYd d, emp e 
            where p.PRODUCTIVITYID=d.PRODUCTIVITYID and e.empno=p.employeeid
            )
    SELECT *
    FROM   pivot_data
    PIVOT (
              max(workhrs)        --<-- pivot_clause
          FOR pdate --<-- pivot_for_clause

         IN  ('03/08/2016')    --<-- pivot_in_clause         
)
```

result is only two rows

```
EMPNO   ENAME   MEALPANELTY '03/08/2016'
7698    BLAKE   -           8.12
7698    BLAKE   4           50
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: I don't see an issue, it is broken into two subsets by `mealpanelty` (4 and -) before the actual pivot.

Comment: The results are as expected, you are asking the MAX workhours for one date, grouped per Employee and Mealpanelty. Thus it is normal to only have one row per EMployee/mealpanelty combination. If that's not what you want should post a data sample of the results you want to achieve

Comment: @Koshinae So what you suggest for query to be re-written.

Comment: Skip mealpanelty column, if you can do it.

Comment: @Koshinae If I remove it then only single row shows.

Answer (score -1):

Pivot does something like this.

```
with pivot_data (PDATE,   EMPNO,   ENAME,   WORKHRS, MEALPANELTY) as 
(
select '03/08/2016','7698','BLAKE',50,4  from dual union all
select '03/08/2016','7698','BLAKE',7.58,null from dual union all   
select '03/08/2016','7698','BLAKE',8.12,null  from dual union all  
select '03/08/2016','7698','BLAKE',7.34,null  from dual union all  
select '03/08/2016','7698','BLAKE',8.02,null  from dual)      
select EMPNO,ENAME,MEALPANELTY
 ,case when PDATE ='03/08/2016' then max(WORKHRS)end --list of value  from in(  IN  ('03/08/2016')  )  

 from pivot_data
 group by  PDATE,EMPNO,ENAME,MEALPANELTY;
```

Try to add unique column in your table.

Comment: I need to automate not static values

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: all five rows shows be shown with pivot as like single query

Comment: It seems there is grouping with data during pivot

Comment: In my example i showed you what pivot does. If you want 5 rows add unique value to each row.